# What JS objects can be added through appendChild()?

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, dhtml, extend

I am trying to extend the DOM. I "subclassed" from the Div element:

```
var Subclass = function() {}
Subclass.prototype = document.createElement('div');
Subclass.constructor = Subclass;

var obj = new Subclass();
var obj.innerHTML = 'test';
document.body.appendChild(obj); // Exception: Node cannot be inserted ... point in the hierarchy
```

So if an object's prototype being a DOM object won't do, what is the requirement for an object to be inserted into the DOM?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779880/in-javascript-can-you-extend-the-dom

Answer (score 0):

This actually works in Firefox.. Sort of, anyway. It won't actually create new elements when doing new Subclass, but keeps using the same.

In any case, I would say the DOM objects themselves are "special" in the way that only they can be appendChild'd.

Comment: It does not work in Firefox. `var obj = new Subclass(); obj.innerHTML = "test"; document.body.appendChild(obj);` gives the error.

Comment: Odd, it worked for me. It actually added the div into the document.

Answer (score 0):

According to W3C specification `appendChild()`:

1. Returns `Node`.
2. Throws `DOMException`.
3. Requires one argument of type `Node`.

From [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247):

```
Node appendChild(in Node newChild) raises(DOMException);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extend only div elements then may be you can do that by

```
HTMLDivElement.prototype.newFunction = function () { //'this' will get that div dom }
```

then it will extend only the div elements.. works on FF, don't know about other browsers.

hope this may help you.