# Javascript : How to create global functions & variables

Tags: javascript, function, object, element, global

I would like to create a new function that I can use on elements, like this:

```
document.getElementById("element").myNewFunction();
```

I'm not talking about this:

```
document.getElementById("element").myNewFunction = function(){
   doSomething...
}
```

Because this works on that element only, but how should I create global function what I can use on all elements like the ones what are built in to JavaScript?

Comment: it' bad style i think. Instead of this, create some hash where key is id of the element, and the value - function. i will be more simple to understand and use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use Element's prototype to extend its functionality:

```
Element.prototype.myNewFunction = function() { 
      // your code...
};
```

Now you can call this method on any element object.

**Edit:** I've just had a quick check around, and it appears that this will not work for IE7 and below, and IE8 might be iffy.

**Edit 2:** Also as Eli points out it's probably not best practice to extend objects you don't own. Given this and shaky IE support you might want to consider a simple procedural function:

```
function myFunction(element) {
  // your code...

  // which may or may not return an object or value
  return blah;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, element's prototype? so there are prototypes for all kinds of object types? I never really understood how prototypes are working :)

Comment: Read http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html to understand Prototypal inheritance

Answer (score 5):

See this question: [In Javascript, can you extend the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779880/in-javascript-can-you-extend-the-dom).

While it is possible to do, its generally considered bad practice to change the functionality of objects you don't own.

Answer (score 1):

Prototype (the library) does this, extends the native (built-in) DomElement class by adding methods to its prototype. It doesn't work in old IEs though so I'd recommend against it.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Object.prototype.myNeweFunction=function(){
 doSomthing..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click = function () {
    alert('HAI!');
};

document.links[0].click();
```

Figure out right object to extend by querying `document.getElementById("element").constructor`