# Is it possible to add a method to the DOM document?

Tags: javascript, methods, domdocument

I am developing a function to find a particular element within another element identifier (similar to getElementById but that applies to any other element) ... Because this throws me arror:

```
var ancestor = document.getElementById('divAncestor');
var child = ancestor.getElementById('divChild');
```

I know, HTML specifies that ids must be unique but reality proves that often running scripts that can have items with the same ids. So, thats the reason why I'm not simply calling the child like this:

```
var ancestor = document.getElementById('divChild');
```

The first option was to add this function to each HTML element, or at least the divs (because that's what interests me identify). The second, and is the one I prefer, is to add a method to the dom document and call from there by passing the ID of the father and son as parameters.

Is this possible?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What? Can you please explain what you are tying to do. IDs **must** be unique... that is by ***definition***!

Comment: "HTML specifies that ids must be unique" yes it does. "but reality proves that often running scripts that can have items with the same ids." no, they can't. **IDs must be unique**. use classes instead if you have no other way of differentiating.

Comment: Quite apart from @Neal's comment: Do keep in mind that a reference to a particular DOM Element is not the same as a reference to a DOM Fragment. You're referencing a node, not it's children and therefore, you don't have a DOM-tree. you can use `ancestor.getElementsByTagName('*')` and `ancestor.children` to get whatever it is you're after...

Comment: Thanks Elias, that's what i did. But the real probleme is to add a method to the DOM document.

The rest of the comments were not helpful. I already know the definitions, and you can have two objects with the same ID (I have done), but should not be. But not my case, I NEED two equals ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not discussing the bosh with non-unique ids, I will answer your actual question:

> Is it possible to add a method to the DOM document?

Yes, see [How to extend the DOM with JS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779880/1048572). But do not do it! The reasons are discussed very well in Kangax' article [What’s wrong with extending the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/).

> The second method, was to add a method to the dom document and call from there by passing the ID of the father and son as parameters.

You could do this, yes, and would not cause too much harm. I'd guess it works well in all browsers, as you won't have garbage-collection problems etc. anyway with a static function.

Yet I can't see a good reason to do it. It sounds to me like abusing the `document` variable as a namespace, while any other global variable or namespace object would've done it as well. For not creating possible (future) collisions, a dedicated namespace would be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
document.querySelector("div#divAncestor div#divChild");
```

This gets the first `div` with `id="divChild"` in the `div` with `id="divAncestor"`

While ID's ***Must*** be unique, as per the specification, it is indeed *possible* that they aren't.
<sup>(Browsers deal with it just fine)</sup>
While your priority "should be" to prevent this, the code above works.

In case there are multiple ancestors or children, this should work:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div#divAncestor div#divChild");
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hr9X2/2/)**

These querySelectors work like css selectors. Select classes like: `div.className`, multiple elements like this: `div, p, h1`, etc.

Comment: I wouldn't be sure that *all* browsers deal with this just fine.

Comment: @Bergi: I have yet to see a browser that can't handle a non-unique `id`.
The `querySelector` [is supported by IE 8+, FF 3.5+, and as early as Chrome 4](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13)