# Using this to call other function in callback

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I am trying to call a function inside a callback function with `addEventListener`

The code I am using is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table id="outside">
      <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
    </table>
    <script>
      function avis(n) {

          return n;
      }
      var c = document.getElementById('outside');
      function babe() {
          if(this.avis(c) == 'outside') {
              console.log('yuck');
          }
      }
      var el = document.getElementById("outside");
      el.addEventListener("click", babe,  false);
    </script>
```

This above code gives error like  `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.\

But when I use code like:

```
function babe() {
    if(this.id == 'outside') {
        console.log('yuck');
    }
}
```

It works fine ..

So my question is... is it possible to call another function with `this.functionname()` inside the callback?

Comment: Call function and assign to variable and use this variable into if condition

Comment: `this` inside an event handler refers to an object on which event was raised. So with `.functionname()` you call its method.

Comment: @SerG so you mean the this on event handler refers to the element which is clicked on ??

Comment: Yep, table object in your case.

Comment: @SerG it would be really helpful if you post an answer as an example ..i would surely accept it ..can i use this.anyfunctionname() inside the eventhandler

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @SerG see i just want to call a function inside the callback with this.afunctionname() inside event handler ...is it possible ??

Comment: Why do you think you need call it like `this.afunctionname()`? And look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.avis` is not a function, `avis` is

```js
      function avis(n) {

          return n;
      }
      var c = document.getElementById('outside');
      function babe() {
          if(avis(c).id == 'outside') {
              console.log('yuck');
          }
      }
      var el = document.getElementById("outside");
      el.addEventListener("click", babe,  false);
```

```html
    <table id="outside">
      <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
    </table>
```

### Further note

This inside babe refers to the element `id:outside` which you created the event handler on. It is called by JavaScript in a element context (like [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) does). But you don't need the `avis` function. Just check for `this.id`, unless you need `avis` to do something else

```js
      var c = document.getElementById('outside');
      function babe() {
          if(this.id == 'outside') {
              console.log('yuck');
          }
      }
      var el = document.getElementById("outside");
      el.addEventListener("click", babe,  false);
```

```html
    <table id="outside">
      <tr><td id="t1">one</td></tr>
      <tr><td id="t2">two</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: i know i can make the code run by using just function name like avis() //my question is can i use like this.anyfunctionname() in the callback ??

Comment: can you tell me what this refers inside event handler ??..dos this refer to the element which is clicked

Comment: @saptamasree Yes it does

Comment: @saptamasree `this` inside the event handlers callback function  is the element, which is clicked on. `this.anyfunctionname` does not exist in this context.

Comment: ..thanx for your answer...actually can i use any function like this.afunctionname() inside event handler in any case ..if i can please edit ur ans with an example..it would be a lot helpful ..:)

Comment: wow exactly..in this case this represents the element which is called on ryt ??

Comment: Ryt!! It is so as you say

Comment: Think twice before extend DOM element. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779880/in-javascript-can-you-extend-the-dom

Comment: @Serg I think you are right. But DOM element data is beyond the scope of this question.